# "Спасли Родину от нападения фашистами". Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в написании

Tags: грамматика, стилистика, егэ

В сочинении написала: "...спасли Родину от нападения фашистами". Есть ли здесь ошибка? Если да, то грубая ли она?

Comment: Ксения, поясните, пожалуйста, вы описываете Великую Отечественную войну или другое событие?

Comment: Про ВОВ, да. Точно не помню, как написала, но скорее всего защитили Родину от нападения фашистами. И да, я грамотна во всем,сама не понимаю, как могла так написать)

Answer (score 8):

По-моему, здесь две ошибки: одна - грубая грамматическая, другая - едва заметная стилистическая.

Первая ошибка: неверно выбран падеж. Корректно: нападение (кого?) фашистов. Здесь вопрос КОГО можно заменить вопросом ЧЬЕ, речь идет о принадлежности, требуется родительный падеж (фашистов).

Вторая ошибка: неудачно выбрано сочетание "спасли от нападения", которое имеет смысл "предотвратили нападение". Как известно, предотвратить нападение фашистов не удалось, значит, лучше сказать просто "спасли от фашистов".

Comment: *Как известно, предотвратить нападение фашистов не удалось* @М_Г помилуйте, да про 41-й давно забыли. Это дети так сейчас пишут сочинения про "спасение" Крыма. Их так учат. Не грамматике, разумеется, а стилистике.

Comment: @Мимоходов,  в вопросе "спасли Родину", а не "спасли Крым". Дамаю, это все же про ВОВ.

Comment: Я так не думаю. Вот примерчик. https://videouroki.net/razrabotki/prezentatsiya-dlya-nachalnykh-klassov-krym-nasha-rodina.html

Comment: @Мимоходов, Мы ведь про русский язык здесь говорим? Так там просто издевательство над языком в угоду политической моде.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, о чем вы. Я говорю про реальные сочинения, которые крымские дети 1-3-5-го классов пишут. Нет, я, конечно, могу ошибаться, но если такое человек любого возрасти ***пишет***, то это заставляет думать о вполне современном "новоязе", прививаемом сегодня и сейчас.

Answer (score 4):

*Грамматическая* ошибка - явная и состоит она в том, что в таком падеже нельзя употребить слово "фашисты", поскольку существительное "*нападение*" образовано от **непереходного** глагола. Это как бы перефразированное выражение "фашисты напали Родину" (прямое дополнение обычно соответствует переходному глаголу, а здесь - непереходный), а не "на Родину". Для сравнения изменим глагол на **переходный** "*поработить* (Родину)", отглагольное существительное - "*порабощение*". Соответственно:

> ... спасли Родину от *порабощения фашистами*.

Как вы уже заметили, была и *смысловая* ошибка: о *спасении от нападения* фашист**ов** можно было бы сказать в случае, если бы нападение (военное наступление на территорию страны) не состоялось, а исторически оно было.

Answer (score 1):

Да, конечно. )))

"Они" же не "фашистами" (с их помощью, использованием) Родину спасли от нападения, а ***(от) фашистов***. Падеж явно не тот.

Это или с грамматикой совсем плохо, или с пониманием. Ошибка грубая, не сомневайтесь.